# How to generate a public key in wallet rpc commands

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc, public-key, address-generation

I'm trying to generate a public key associated with a wallet. How would I do this using the wallet rpc commands, I couldn't find a command in reference docs which does this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I expect the pair

```
getnewaddress  ( "label" "address_type" )
getaddressinfo  "address"
```

will generate a new pubkey and tell you what it is

---

The same commands are supported by bitcoin-qt console so I can easily demonstrate it thusly ...

```
getnewaddress
bc1q************************************5e

getaddressinfo bc1q************************************5e
{
  "address": "bc1q************************************5e",
  [...]
  "pubkey": "03**************************************************************4d",
  [...]
}
```